# Why is my neural network not learning, while a theoretically identical one is?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, directed-acyclic-graphs

So I decided to implement a neural network in Pytorch which operates on a neuron-to-neuron basis, instead of a layer-by-layer one. As such, I made this Neuron class:

```
class Neuron(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, name, activation=nn.ReLU()):
        self.name = name

        super(Neuron, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(n_inputs, 1)
        self.activation = activation
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.linear.weight, nonlinearity='relu')

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.activation(self.linear(x))
```

and implemented a directed acyclic graph-net:

```
class DAGNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, description_string, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create a neural network based on a directed acyclic graph.
        @param description_string: A string describing the DAG.

        Example string:

        A->C,D,E;B->C,D,E;C->F,G,H;D->F,G,H;E->F,G,H;F->I,J,K;G->I,J,K;H->I,J,K;I->L;J->L;K->L;L;

        This implements a simple neural network with two inputs, three hidden layers, and one output layer.
        However, the DAG structure allows much more general networks to be constructed.
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # First, create a standard directed acyclic graph with the information parsed from the string.
        # This will help us set up the actual neurons later.
        self.dag = {}
        for node in description_string.split(';'):
            if node == '':
                continue
            if '->' not in node:
                # Last node in the string has no outputs
                self.dag[node] = []
                continue
            node_name, inputs = node.split('->')
            inputs = inputs.split(',')
            self.dag[node_name] = inputs

        # Reverse each edge in the topological sort to get the input edges for each neuron.
        self.input_edges = {}
        for node, edges in self.dag.items():
            for edge in edges:
                if edge in self.input_edges:
                    self.input_edges[edge].append(node)
                else:
                    self.input_edges[edge] = [node]

        # Now, create a neuron for each node in the DAG.
        # Make sure to correctly count the number of inputs for each neuron.
        self.neurons = {}
        for node_name, inputs in self.dag.items():
            n_inputs = 0

            if node_name not in self.input_edges:
                n_inputs = 2  # (x, y) input neuron
            else:
                n_inputs += len(self.input_edges[node_name])

            n_outputs = len(self.dag[node_name]) if len(self.dag[node_name]) > 0 else 1

            self.neurons[node_name] = Neuron(n_inputs, n_outputs, node_name)

        # Topologically sort the neurons to ensure that the inputs to each neuron are computed before the neuron itself.
        self.ts = TopologicalSorter(self.dag)

        self.so = list(reversed(list(self.ts.static_order())))

        self.model = nn.Sequential(*[self.neurons[node_name] for node_name in self.so])

    def forward(self, x):
        # Run the input through the DAG to get the output.
        # Make sure to correctly pass the inputs to each neuron.

        node_names = list(self.neurons.keys())
        outputs = {}

        # The input (x) gets loaded into nodes that don't have any inputs
        for node_name in self.so:
            if node_name not in self.input_edges:
                outputs[node_name] = self.neurons[node_name](x)

        # The rest of the nodes get their inputs from the outputs of other nodes
        for node_name in self.so:
            if node_name in self.input_edges:
                inputs = []
                for input_node in self.input_edges[node_name]:
                    # Get the subpart of the input node's output that corresponds to this node's input
                    inputs.append(torch.hsplit(outputs[input_node], len(self.dag[input_node]))[self.dag[input_node].index(node_name)])
                outputs[node_name] = self.neurons[node_name](torch.cat(inputs, dim=1))

        return outputs[list(self.so)[-1]]
```

Now, I'm trying to train a `DAGNet("A->D,E,F;B->D,E,F;C->D,E,F;D->G,H,I;E->G,H,I;F->G,H,I;G->J;H->J;I->J;J;")`. This seems mathematically equivalent to a neural network with hidden layers of sizes 3, 3, and 3 neurons each. However, this network's loss does not decrease past about 0.33, while a standard pytorch network with nn.Linear layers of sizes 3, 3, and 3 neurons works perfectly.

Is there some way in which my implementation is not equivalent to the Pytorch network? The training seems to run at approximately the same speed.

Comment: Your proposed DAGNet appears to have just two hidden layers of 3 neurons each, not three as you've written?

Comment: The one with three layers has the same issue of getting stuck at 0.33...guess I'm gonna have to do some gradients by hand.